# T4 to generate DTO' and Nullable Datatypes

Tags: t4, dto

I'm trying to generate DTO's with T4.  I found a great blog post that does exactly what i'm looking for but it explodes on Nullable data types.

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/03/11/code-generation-with-t4-an-entities-to-dto-example.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

This generates code with Nullable types like below

```
   [DataMember(Name="terminationCFDate")]
    public System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] TerminationCFDate
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

I am looking for something like below

```
    [DataMember(Name="terminationCFDate")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> TerminationCFDate 
    { 
       get; set; 
    }
```

I am very new to T4.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just use "?" instead?

Comment: After playing with the template, its simply reflection and easy to modify.  FYI, nullable types from Type.getproperties() returns the base type so its a little ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the template.  It was using reflections.